# Setting output of layout-render to a variable (stripes)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, stripes

I'm trying to reuse a variable that's been set in a jsp and used in a Stripes layout-render.

Main page: /index.jsp

Layout Render page: /jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp

My /jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp has a c:set variable called ${oauth_url}. But when I call the layout-render page via *s:layout-render name="/jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp"*, I would expect to be able to use any variables that are in there, as if I was including that script. But I can't use that ${oauth_url} in index.jsp.

I've even tried doing this, which unsurprisingly doesn't work:

```
<c:set var="oauth_url" value="<s:layout-render name="/jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp" 
buttonType="signup"/>"/>
<s:link href="${oauth_url}">
```

How can I reuse a variable that's being set in /jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp? Basically, how can I make it global to the index.jsp page so it can be used in other places?

If I want to just use c:set values declared in /jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp, should I import with a different tag instead of s:layout-render? I still want to pass it some attributes - like buttonType.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to do, but did you try adding `scope="request"` to the `<c:set ... />` tag?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is use a variable in index.jsp that is being set with the c:set tag in my /jsp/widgets/signin/oAuthUrl.jsp file.  Seems like whatever I set in the files I call in layout-render is not available in the global scope. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @acdhirr Looks like that worked! Answer the question below so I can mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default variables set with `<c:set ... />` have the `page` scope and will not be available outside that page.

To make a variable available to other templates higher up the nesting hierarchy for a request, use the `request` scope:

```
<c:set var="…" value="…" scope="request" />
```